# org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate in spring-retry support for Spring 5.0.X

Tags: spring-batch, spring-retry

I'm trying to upgrade spring to 5.0.6.RELEASE.
Just checking to see if org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate in spring-retry project is supported with spring 5.0+ framework version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; the current version is 1.2.2.RELEASE - it works fine with Spring 5.

Comment: Thanks on the confirmation. I will try it out.